# Mediaconvert passrole issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-media-convert

aws returns AccessDeniedException exception (x role is not authorized to perform: iam: PassRole), when I try to create mediaconvert job.

this is how I attach iam role to lambda function in serverless.yml

```
converter:
    handler: src/handlers/videoConverter.handler
    role: arn:aws:iam::<X>:role/VODLambdaRole
    events:
      - s3:
          bucket: <Y>
          event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
          existing: true
```

this is part of the **VODLambdaRole** policy, that is necessarry to pass role:

```
{
            "Action": [
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::<X>:role/MediaConvertRole"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Sid": "PassRole"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "mediaconvert:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Sid": "MediaConvertService"
        },
```

Ps: I double checked if I had incorrect arns, but they're correct
Pps: I even attached AdministratorAccess to that role, but it returns the same error...

Comment: solved:
if anyone will face this issue ever, just add 'sts:AssumeRole'  in the actions array ( with "iam:Passrole"